# Many DNS requests on website

Tags: google-chrome, dns

I noticed that visiting some websites (with google chrome in my case) many DNS requests are made. (I saw a large peek in Pi-Hole) i.e. the german website of ToyRUs contains links to all the instances for the other countries in a country selection menu.

It seems like without cliking the links and without the website actively queriing these other pages still there is one DNS request for every top-level domain that this website is available at.

Is this a known behaviour of browsers (Firing DNS requests for all domains on a site) ? Or is this special for this website ?

Answer (score 2):

Many browsers try to anticipate which links you will click so they can provide a faster response. What you are observing is probably part of that.

---

Related: [link prefetch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_prefetching)